# Add a header in Project with COM Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-project, office-automation

I used COM Interop to automatically create a MS-Project file and I added few tasks in it.

I am trying to automatically add a header and a footer in this file similarly than the way it works in MS-Word as below :

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section in myDoc.Sections)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range headerRange = section.Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
    headerRange.Fields.Add(headerRange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage);
    headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;
}
```

But I don't find document on the subject, is it in the least possible?

**Edit**

I have tried with this syntax :

```
Application.FilePageSetupHeader , 1, "Date:  &[Date]"
```

But it looks like a VBA syntax and I am using C# with Interop COM.

I've tried with this instruction that I found while doing some tests :

```
project.Application.FilePageSetupHeader(1, PjAlignment.pjCenter, "Date");
```

But it alway gives me this error *System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The argument value is not valid.'*

Does anybody know a clean syntax in C# or the way FilePageSetupHeader works in C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all the parameters of the function FilePageSetupHeader are optionals, it seems that the first parameter, the view is required. So I had to get it like this (I have only one view in my project) :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Views views = project.Views;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.View view = null;
foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.View vw in views)
{
  view = vw;
}
```

Then you can use it edit your header :

```
projApp.Application.FilePageSetupHeader(view, Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.PjAlignment.pjCenter,
                                                "Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

**Note :** projApp is a Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application object.

Answer (score 1):

The headers and footers in MS Project are rudimentary. There is a single string property for each section (left, center, right); formatting is done via format codes.

For example, this adds the date to the center header:

```
Application.FilePageSetupHeader , PjAlignment.pjCenter, "Date:  &[Date]"
```

[FilePageSetupHeader Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/application-filepagesetupheader-method-project)

[FilePageSetupFooter Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/application-filepagesetupfooter-method-project)

Comment: Notice the first argument is the name of the view or report and it is optional. Do not put a 1 as the first argument. I updated my answer to change the second argument to the intrinsic constant (e.g. 1 = `PjAlignment.pjCenter`).